# git-svn init inexplicably hangs on a new Windows machine

Tags: windows, svn, git-svn

I am trying to check out an SVN repository using `git-svn` on Windows. The repository has password auth over `https`. On my old machine, I can create a new empty directory and do this:

```
git svn init -s --username jsmith https://companyname.website/svn/repositoryname
```

and after a second or two, it will return with

```
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tempdir/.git/
```

And return me to the prompt. However, on my new machine, if I issue the same command, it hangs after printing out the status message. It prints out the status message, but does not return me to the prompt.

Similar questions are about cloning a large SVN repo, and answers all suggest that I start with just doing init by itself and then selectively fetch recent revisions, which is a good idea, but I can't even get the init to complete.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect an authentication issue, but I'm not getting an error message, `git svn init` simply never returns me to the prompt.

Comment: Have you looked at [this Stack Overflow question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878976/why-does-git-svn-fetch-command-seem-to-be-stuck-and-does-nothing)? Also, do you have access to the repository via SSH? In general, HTTPS stinks for Git. I would recommend using SSH and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have SSH access. I have found that the init call returns promptly if I remove the `-s` flag. Why is this, though? Possibly relevant, the repository in question was originally created without branches, the main code was moved to /trunk in r18.

Incidentally I can check out the latest revision in `svn` easily. Following the advice in that other thread, I tried cloning only the last revision, but even that appears to be taking forever. It's not creating `.git/svn/metadata` either.

Comment: Mainly I'm confused because all these commands work just fine on my old machine and I can't find the difference. The new machine is a work computer with Azure Active Directory, I think. I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Well, please provide more details to your question such as Windows version and other info if possible such as the Azure Active Directory stuff.